# Silence output from SimpleXMLRPCServer

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I am running an xml-rpc server using SimpleXMLRPCServer from the stdlib.

My code looks something like this:

```
import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import socket

class RemoteStarter:
    def start(self):
        return 'foo'

rs = RemoteStarter()
host = socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())[0]
port = 9000
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((host, port))
server.register_instance(rs)
server.serve_forever()
```

every time the 'start' method gets called remotely, the server prints an access line like this:

```
<server_name> - - [10/Mar/2010 13:06:20] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

I can't figure out a way to silence the output so it doesn't print these access lines to stdout.

anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the answer is:

pass `logRequests=False` to SimpleXMLRPCServer when you create it:

```
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((host, port), logRequests=False)
```